# Parallel computations with for each and %dopar% do not generate a file

Tags: r, doparallel

I am trying to use the doParallel package with foreach and %dopar% for the first time as I need to increase the speed of my computation.

Although the code is executed without raising any error, the file is not stored in the output folder.

I have a list of file paths (list_files) and a function (my_function) that I previously validated using sapply. When I use sapply, the output is stored in the output location. Using foreach and %dopar% returns no output in my output location.

```
# Define my function and call it my_function
my_function <- function(input_dir, output_dir) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = {     
      file <- read.csv(input_dir,sep = "\t", col.names = c("column1", "column2"))
      file <- as_tibble(file)
      file_noNA <- file %>% filter(!is.na(column1))
      name <- substr(input_dir, nchar(input_dir)-8, nchar(input_dir)-4)
      save(file_noNA, file = paste0(output_dir, name, ".rds"))
    }
  )
}

library("parallel")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

# Set number of cores
n.cores <- 5   

# Check doParallel package
doParallel::registerDoParallel(n.cores)
getDoParWorkers()

# Apply function with parallel computing
foreach(i = list_files) %dopar% function(x) {
         my_function(
           input_dir = x, 
           output_dir = output_location)
  }
```

This is what I have tried (without success):

- Assigned the result
- used foreach(i = list_files, .combine = 'c') %dopar% function(x) {...}
- Used a single file instead of list_files
- Reduced the number of cores

Do I need to add an export statement, e.g.
.export=ls(envir=globalenv())
or
.export=ls() ?

Comment: You may need to assign the output to an object

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the output, @akrun

Comment: Thanks - I have added a simplified example for my_function, @akrun.

Comment: The last expression in the function is to `save` ie. you are not returning the data.  Maybe you need to return `file_noNA` as the last expression

Comment: It is possible that the the objects created in the env may not be accessible.  Try with `.export`

Comment: i hope that fixes your issue

Comment: Like this @akrun? - foreach(i = list_files, .export) %dopar% function(x) { ... }

Comment: i menat to `.export = c("output_location"))`.  Also, if some packages are required `.packages = c("dplyr", "tibble")` as you are using `as_tibble` within the function

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you added the `.packages`

Comment: These are some of the common issues that I encounter and normally it gets resolved after that.  As I said eariler, we cannot test your code

Comment: Not sure if this is the main issue but one closing bracket is missing in your code `save(file_noNA, file = paste0(output_dir, name, ".rds")`.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue - there was a problem with the packages. Thank, you @akrun ! Instead of using .packages, is it also possible to use .export=ls(envir=globalenv()) or .export=ls() ?